# Remove option from select when selecting them and add the value to a div. When clicking on the div, return the option to the select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select>` with some options. When selecting an option, I want it to disappear from the `<select>` and appear in a div. Then, when the option is in the div, if I click over it, I want it to disappear and return to the select.

I have this code:

jQuery:

```
$(".car").click(function()
{
    var $id = $('#selector option:selected').val();
    var $text = $('#selector option:selected').text();

    $("#selector option[value='" + $id + "']").remove();

    $('.cars').append('<div class="hey" id="' + $id + '">' + $text + '</div>');


    $(".hey").click(function () {
        $(this).remove();

        var $value = $(this).attr('id');
        var $text1 = $(this).text();

        $('#selector').append('<option class="car" value="' + $value +'">' + $text1 +'</option>');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="cars">
    </div>
</div>

<select id="selector">
    <option class="car" value="alfaromeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option class="car" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option class="car" value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option class="car" value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jqvtyt7f/

But there are some huge problems. If I select more than a car brand at once, when clicking on a brand name, the brand name returns to the list repeated 2, 3 or 4 times (depending on how many brands are selected and its position)
I also cant reselect an option more than once...

I am a novice with javascript and i have no idea about what is going on. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: for starters you can't use `click` on `<option>` tag cross browser, it's not a standard and isn't supported in all browsers. Use `change` on `<select>` and don't nest event handlers

Comment: Believe it or not, I think it still works. jQuery has quite a few events that are not standard. jQuery will still trigger than event since you are clicking on an option tag. Perhaps not recommended, but it will work.

Comment: @Chris has nothing to do with jQuery..has to do with browsers like IE and safari ... and no, it doesn't work cross browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real reason for using jQuery for this, other than syntactic sugar and cross-browser compatibility (albeit I think that most browsers, including IE 9 and above should work with plain JavaScript). So, while I had time I thought I'd offer a plain JS approach:

```
// pairing both functions within a parent object:
var options = {
    // defining the name of the function:
    'optionToDiv' : function () {

        // this is the changed-<select> element passed
        // automagically from addEventListner() (later):
        var select = this,

            // retrieving the selected <option> from the <select>,
            // by looking at the options collection of the <select>
            // and using the selectedIndex property of the
            // HTMLSelectElement which gives the index of the
            // selected <option> in the collection of options:
            selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex],

            // creating a <span> element for use:
            span = document.createElement('span'),

            // retrieving the <div> element we're adding the
            // <span> to:
            div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

        // setting the data-value property to be equal to
        // the value property of the <option> (for moving the
        // 'option' back into the <select>):
        span.dataset.value = selectedOption.value;

        // setting the text of the <span> to the <option>
        // element's text:
        span.textContent = selectedOption.text;

        // if we already have a <span> (or rather 'child') present
        // in the <div>:
        if (div.children.length) {

            // we append a new Option to the <select> element,
            // here we use the new Option(text, value, selected)
            // constructor; passing in the text of the <span> as,
            // the <option> text, and the data-value of the span as
            // the value:
            select.appendChild(new Option(div.firstChild.textContent, div.firstChild.dataset.value));

            // then we replace the current first-child of the <div>
            // with the newly-created <span>:
            div.replaceChild(span, div.firstChild)
        }
        else {

            // otherwise we simply append the newly-created
            // <span> element to the <div>:
            div.appendChild(span);
        }

        // and then remove the selected <option> from the <select>:
        selectedOption.parentNode.removeChild(selectedOption);
    },

    // name of the function that handles moving the <span>
    // back to the <select> element (as an <option>):
    'optionToSelect' : function () {

        // finding the <select> element:
        var select = document.getElementById('selector');

        // as above, appending a newly-created <option> element
        // using the new Option(text, value, selected) constructor:
        select.appendChild(new Option(this.firstChild.textContent, this.firstChild.dataset.value));

        // removing the first-child of the clicked <div>
        // (which is 'this' in this function):
        this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    }
};

// retrieving the <select> element:
var select = document.getElementById('selector'),

// retrieving the (relevant) <div> element:
    div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

// binding the named-function as the change event-handler
// of the <select> element:
select.addEventListener('change', options.optionToDiv);

// binding the named-function as the click event-handler
// of the <div> element:
div.addEventListener('click', options.optionToSelect);
```

```js
var options = {
  'optionToDiv': function() {
    var select = this,
      selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex],
      span = document.createElement('span'),
      div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');
    span.dataset.value = selectedOption.value;
    span.textContent = selectedOption.text;

    if (div.children.length) {
      select.appendChild(new Option(div.firstChild.textContent, div.firstChild.dataset.value));
      div.replaceChild(span, div.firstChild)
    } else {
      div.appendChild(span);
    }
    selectedOption.parentNode.removeChild(selectedOption);
  },
  'optionToSelect': function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('selector');
    select.appendChild(new Option(this.firstChild.textContent, this.firstChild.dataset.value));
    this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
  }
};

var select = document.getElementById('selector'),
  div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

select.addEventListener('change', options.optionToDiv);
div.addEventListener('click', options.optionToSelect);
```

```css
.hey {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="cars"></div>
</div>
<select id="selector">
  <option class="car" value="alfaromeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option class="car" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="car" value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option class="car" value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nv3L31bm/), for experimentation and development.

As pointed out in the comments, [below, by Steve Padmore], the above solution is not the expected functionality:

> …the logic is incorrect: [it] will only add the first selection to the div, and then nothing more. In the code to add an option to the div, you are adding an option to the select (and then removing the original). You are replacing any item in the div with the latest selection - it should add them…

To correct this improper logic requires only the removal of the `if (div.children.length) / else` block; and replacing it all with the contained – in the `else` – `div.replaceChild(span, div.firstChild)`, which gives the following code (all else as above, so uncommented):

```
var options = {
    'optionToDiv': function () {
        var select = this,
            selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex],
            span = document.createElement('span'),
            div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');
        span.dataset.value = selectedOption.value;
        span.textContent = selectedOption.text;

        // removed the surrounding if/else block,
        // replacing it with this single line which
        // always adds the selected <option> to the
        // <div>:
        div.appendChild(span);

        selectedOption.parentNode.removeChild(selectedOption);
    },
        'optionToSelect': function () {
        var select = document.getElementById('selector');
        select.appendChild(new Option(this.firstChild.textContent, this.firstChild.dataset.value));
        this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    }
};

var select = document.getElementById('selector'),
    div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

select.addEventListener('change', options.optionToDiv);
div.addEventListener('click', options.optionToSelect);
```

```js
var options = {
  'optionToDiv': function() {
    var select = this,
      selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex],
      span = document.createElement('span'),
      div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');
    span.dataset.value = selectedOption.value;
    span.textContent = selectedOption.text;

    div.appendChild(span);

    selectedOption.parentNode.removeChild(selectedOption);
  },
  'optionToSelect': function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('selector');
    select.appendChild(new Option(this.firstChild.textContent, this.firstChild.dataset.value));
    this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
  }
};

var select = document.getElementById('selector'),
  div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

select.addEventListener('change', options.optionToDiv);
div.addEventListener('click', options.optionToSelect);
```

```css
.hey {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.cars span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="cars"></div>
</div>
<select id="selector">
  <option class="car" value="alfaromeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option class="car" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="car" value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option class="car" value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nv3L31bm/1/), for experimentation and development.

Of course it's worth noting the other obvious flaw with the existing answer: that because the movement of the `<option>` is based upon the `change` event, it means the first `<option>` can never appear in the list – since selecting an `<option>` removes it from the `<select>` and so the first `<option>` becomes selected once more, preventing the `<select>` from 'changing.'

Therefore this update uses a simple function to prepend a `'Please select'` `<option>` to the `<select>` element:

```
var options = {

    // name of the 'initialisation' function:
    'init': function () {

        // getting the <select> element:
        var select = document.getElementById('selector');

        // inserting a new Option before the current firstChild
        // of the <select> element, using the
        // new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)
        // constructor:
        select.insertBefore(new Option('Please select', '-1', true, true), select.firstChild);
    },
    'optionToDiv': function () {
        var select = this,
            selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex],
            span = document.createElement('span'),
            div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');
        span.dataset.value = selectedOption.value;
        span.textContent = selectedOption.text;

        div.appendChild(span);
        selectedOption.parentNode.removeChild(selectedOption);
    },
        'optionToSelect': function () {
        var select = document.getElementById('selector');
        select.appendChild(new Option(this.firstChild.textContent, this.firstChild.dataset.value));
        this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    }
};

options.init();

var select = document.getElementById('selector'),
    div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

select.addEventListener('change', options.optionToDiv);
div.addEventListener('click', options.optionToSelect);
```

```js
var options = {
  'init': function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('selector');
    select.insertBefore(new Option('Please select', '-1', true, true), select.firstChild);
  },
  'optionToDiv': function(e) {
    var select = this,
      selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex],
      span = document.createElement('span'),
      div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');
    span.dataset.value = selectedOption.value;
    span.textContent = selectedOption.text;

    div.appendChild(span);
    selectedOption.parentNode.removeChild(selectedOption);
  },
  'optionToSelect': function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('selector');
    select.appendChild(new Option(this.firstChild.textContent, this.firstChild.dataset.value));
    this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
  }
};

// calling the initialisation function:
options.init();

var select = document.getElementById('selector'),
  div = document.querySelector('#myDiv > div.cars');

select.addEventListener('change', options.optionToDiv);
div.addEventListener('click', options.optionToSelect);
```

```css
.hey {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.cars span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="cars"></div>
</div>
<select id="selector">
  <option class="car" value="alfaromeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option class="car" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="car" value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option class="car" value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nv3L31bm/2/), for experimentation and development.

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement).
- [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
- [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild).
- [`Option()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).

Comment: Nice alternative, it's always good to see vanilla JavaScript solutions. However the logic is incorrect: It will only add the first selection to the div, and then nothing more. In the code to add an option to the div, you are adding an option to the select (and then removing the original). You are replacing any item in the div with the latest selection - it should add them, otherwise you could end up with one item in the div, and none left in the select list. The 'div.firstChild' inside 'if (div.children.length) {}' is accessing the 'text' child - not the span. Just a heads up...

Comment: Thanks, as regards the incorrect logic I somehow misread the question and assumed that was the intended logic. I'll correct that in a few minutes, once I've had breakfast. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the change event of the select list rather than on each option in it.

No need to use $("#selector option[value='" + $id + "']").remove(); for the selection to remove - you already have the selected option, so $('#selector option:selected').remove(); is sufficient.

Also, I'd add the item to the Div before removing from the list, just in case there is an issue adding it to the Div, you will still have the item in the list...

Finally, just check that you do not already have the item in the list before adding it!

So:

```js
$("#selector").change(function() {
  var $id = $('#selector option:selected').val();
  var $text = $('#selector option:selected').text();
  $('#selector option:selected').remove();

  $('.cars').append('<div class="hey" id="' + $id + '">' + $text + '</div>');


  $(".hey").click(function() {

    var $value = $(this).attr('id');
    var $text1 = $(this).text();

    if ($("#selector option[value='" + $value + "']").val() === undefined) {
      $('#selector').append('<option class="car" value="' + $value + '">' + $text1 + '</option>');
    }
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Slightly cleaner is:

```js
var carDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv').querySelector('.cars');

$("#selector").change(function() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.id = $('#selector option:selected').val();
  newDiv.innerHTML = $('#selector option:selected').text();
  carDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

  $(newDiv).click(function() {
    putBackInList(this);
  });

  $('#selector option:selected').remove();
});

function putBackInList(item) {
  if ($("#selector option[value='" + item.id + "']").val() === undefined) {
    $('#selector').append(new Option(item.innerHTML, item.id));
  }
  $(item).remove();
}
```

This adds a click function to the each div element to call a single function to do the work, rather than repeating the function for the 'hey' class every time a selection is made from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few issues here from what I can see, as well as a few inefficiencies. I think you are adding the click event to `.hey` too many times. You are adding it to all elements with `.hey` each time an option is clicked. See this:

```
$("#selector").click('.car', function()
{
    var $id = $(this).val(),    //$(this) represents the element clicked
        $text = $(this).text();

    $(this).remove();   //again, $(this) represents the element

    $('.cars').append('<div class="hey" id="' + $id + '">' + $text + '</div>');

});


$("#myDiv").click('.hey', function () {
    $(this).remove();

    var $value = $(this).attr('id');
    var $text1 = $(this).text();

    $('#selector').append('<option class="car" value="' + $value +'">' + $text1 +'</option>');
});
```

Here's what I did:

1. Used `$(this)` in the selector click event for efficiency.
2. Took the click event for `.hey` and moved it outside of the `.car` click event.
3. Instead of applying the click events to the elements themselves, I added them to their parents using what jQuery refers to as `[context][1]`. Since you are adding DOM elements to the stack after adding these listeners, you have to re-add them each time. Providing context like I have, you no longer have to worry about this.

Untested, but I feel good about it.

Comment: please test this in IE... is not a  new issue that click isn't supported on `<option>` ... neither is `hide()` which works in some browsers but not all. SO is littered with lots of posts to support this claim

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

HTML

```
 <div id="myDiv">
    <div class="cars">
    </div>
</div>


<select id="selector">
  <option value="Select a car" class="default">Select a Car</option> 
  <option class="car" value="alfaromeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option class="car" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="car" value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option class="car" value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    var selectedCar = $(this).val(); 

    $(this).find("option:selected").remove(); 
    $("<p/>").addClass("myCar").html(selectedCar).appendTo("#myDiv .cars"); 
}); 

$(".cars").on("click", ".myCar", function(){
    var clickedCar = $(this).text(); 
    $(this).remove(); 
    $("<option/>").val(clickedCar).text(clickedCar).appendTo("select"); 
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1h36p5sg/